# Java Calculation strange result

Tags: java, android, calculation

This is the calculation I want my app to calculate:

```
100000000*90/100
```

Expected result: `90000000`

Javas result: `4100654`

Why is it doing this? The first number (100000000) is coming from an int array and its written into a textView.

Im trying to get 90% of 100000000.

I tried the following:

```
    long test123 = 100000000*90/100;
    Log.i("test123", String.valueOf(test123));
```

Comment: What is the type of your variable?

Comment: int, but its written into a textView right away, so it shouldnt matter, right?

Comment: It probably has to do with priority of operation. it goes `100000000 * 90` then `this number / 100`. You're probably hitting the max int value, then devide it by 100, which give you this result. You could try `100000000 * ( 90/100 )`

Comment: Post [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Your literal numbers are still `int`.  Make them explicitly `long`.

Comment: Thanks, the L worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this operation you should use long or multiply by `90L` that will force answer to be a long. As @Nicolas pointed out by doing `100000000 * 90` you hit max int value hence the result.

Comment: The result is still wrong if I use long with the code show in the question.   Edit: Thanks with the 90L it works. I didnt know you could do this.

Comment: Try with `long test123 = 100000000 * 90L / 100`

Comment: alternatively you can cast the the value , so `(long)100000000*90/100`. The problem was that even though the variable was of long type, the calculated value is resolved as an int before it is assigned to that variable.